# ejb2.0, log4j and EAR project configuration

Tags: websphere, ejb-2.x

I am posting one more question on EJB2.0. I thought my earlier question won't get any answer since EJB2.0 is pretty much outdated technology and nobody wants to work on it any more. But my [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838495/ejb2-x-container-managed-relationship) got answered and I am trying my luck one more time.

I created one simple EJB 2.x entity bean. My entity bean uses another class (UniqueIdGenerator) to generate value of primary key for persistent primary key field.  UniqueIdGenerator uses log4j and JDBC connection, so I configured appropriate build path references for my EJB project.

Added following JARS to buildpath for EJB project
log4j-1.2.16.jar
db2jcc.jar
db2jcc_license_cu.jar

Then I mapped persistent fields to database table fields. Generated code using Prepare for Deployment option in RSA (deploying on WAS).

Created EAR project and using Project References option added EJB project (HMS) to EAR project.

I did not set any other path/classpath.

Started WAS, deployed EAR on WAS and launched Universal Test Client to test entity bean. Using remote interface I tried to create my first bean, I entered the values for fields and clicked on submit on Universal test client. On server side it called ejbCreate() of entity bean but failed when loading UniqueIdGenerator class with error NoClassDefFoundError

Here is stack trace

```
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    com.ibm.ejs.container.CreateFailureException: ; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.log4j.LogManager
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.UtilDelegateImpl.mapSystemException(UtilDelegateImpl.java:235)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.UtilDelegateImpl.wrapException(UtilDelegateImpl.java:743)
    at javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.wrapException(Util.java:296)
    at ejbs._EJSRemoteCMPAddressHome_824957aa_Stub.create(_EJSRemoteCMPAddressHome_824957aa_Stub.java:258)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at com.ibm.etools.utc.model.ReflectionMethodModel.invoke(ReflectionMethodModel.java:65)
    at com.ibm.etools.utc.servlet.InvokeServlet.invoke(InvokeServlet.java:113)
    at com.ibm.etools.utc.servlet.InvokeServlet.doPost(InvokeServlet.java:374)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:864)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)
Caused by: com.ibm.ejs.container.CreateFailureException: ; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.log4j.LogManager
    at ejbs.EJSCMPAddressHomeBean_824957aa.create(EJSCMPAddressHomeBean_824957aa.java:47)
    at ejbs.EJSRemoteCMPAddressHome_824957aa.create(EJSRemoteCMPAddressHome_824957aa.java:28)
    at ejbs._EJSRemoteCMPAddressHome_824957aa_Stub.create(_EJSRemoteCMPAddressHome_824957aa_Stub.java:251)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.log4j.LogManager
    at utils.UniqueLongIdGenerator.(UniqueLongIdGenerator.java:40)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
    at utils.UniqueIdGenerator.(UniqueIdGenerator.java:28)
    at utils.UniqueIdGenerator.(UniqueIdGenerator.java:24)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
    at ejbs.AddressBean.ejbCreate(AddressBean.java:46)
    at ejbs.ConcreteAddress_824957aa.ejbCreate(ConcreteAddress_824957aa.java:122)
    at ejbs.EJSCMPAddressHomeBean_824957aa.create(EJSCMPAddressHomeBean_824957aa.java:33)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.LogManager
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:191)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:660)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:111)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:509)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
    ... 41 more
```

Have I missed anything in the configuration. Do I need to add all the jar files somewhere in EAR project. Isn't it sufficient to set them in the build path for EJB project?

Comment: Adding JARs to the build path only affects compilation.  You need to include the JARs in the actual EAR; if you export the EAR and the JARs aren't included, then the project isn't configured properly.

Comment: Thanks bkail, I investigated more along the same lines and found that I need to add/link third party jars in EAR and also include them in the classpath by adding them to manifest.mf file.

Comment: If you find a comment useful, you can hover to the left of the comment and click the up arrow icon.

Answer (score 1):

I found answer for it on the following links

[How to include external jar in ejb-jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212487/how-to-include-external-jar-in-ejb-jar)

Developerworks Article
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/07/1211_schrag/index.html

You will need to import the third party jars into your EAR project and then setup JAR dependency in your EJB projects MANIFEST.MF file. Once you import external jars into your EAR project, they will be available in explorer for MANIFEST.MF